# Always hide keyboard for Xamarin Forms Android Entry Control (Barcode Scanner input)

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.forms, keyboard, hide

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and mobile app development, so patience & kindness is appreciated! Am building a barcode scanner app with Xamarin.Forms PCL, trying to use MVVM. The scanner is an EXTERNAL bluetooth device (so can't use ZXing).

This project has a fixed requirement to use the scanner as a keyboard-type input and for the user to be able to quickly swap out one bluetooth device for another brand (so no device-specific APIs can be used). A second requirement is for the user to never be allowed to type anything directly into the Entry control. Input should come from the scanner and only the scanner, so therefore we don't ever want the keyboard showing on the scanning page.

There are other pages that have Entry controls where the user WILL need access to the keyboard, and the scanner should be able to stay connected to bluetooth even when a non-scanning screen is displayed. Therefore, I need a reliable way to set the soft keyboard to never be displayed on the scanning page (there is only one input control on this page, and it's intended for scanner use only), but to allow the keyboard to be accessed on other pages.

When on the scanning page, we want focus to always be set on the scanner's Entry control, so when the control gets a Completed event, we do stuff with the value received, then clear out the control and re-set focus on it to prepare for the next scan.

I have been stumbling around writing custom controls and android renderers, and with setting up dependencies (preferred), both with partial success. Either way,  there's a timing issue related to how soon focus is set on the control. If there's not enough of a delay before focus is set, the soft keyboard stays visible. In the code sample provided, I added a short sleep delay, which mostly works to keep the keyboard hidden. However, the keyboard still "flashes" on the screen briefly with each scan, which looks terrible. Would really prefer a solution that is less hacky and ugly.

Is there a good, simple way to remove the soft keyboard entirely for a page, while still allowing an input control to receive focus, so that a scanned barcode can be received? And/or any other suggestions that will allow me to still meet the requirements?

(PS: the scanning page does not currently use MVVM binding. Just trying to get the keyboard to go away first, then will work on binding.)

Below is one way I tried to solve it. There were others as well. NOTE: Ultimately I went with a completely different approach which I'll post as an answer.

The custom control (in PCL):

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyPCL.Views
{
    //See ScanEntryRenderer in the Android project.
    public class ScanEntryControl : Entry
    {
        public ScanEntryControl() { }
    }
}
```

The Xaml page (notice `InputTransparent = "True"` on the custom control. This is so the user cannot directly enter input on the android device. All input must come from the bluetooth scanner).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyPCL.Views"
             x:Class="MyPCL.Views.ScanTestPage"
             Title="Scan Test Page" >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Scanner Test"  />
            <local:ScanEntryControl x:Name="BarcodeEntry" 
                Completed="BarcodeEntryCompleted" 
                InputTransparent="True"/>
            <Label x:Name="ResultLabel"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The code behind for the form:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyPCL.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ScanTestPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ScanTestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BarcodeEntry.Focus();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            BarcodeEntry.Focus();
        }

        private void BarcodeEntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BarcodeEntry.Text))
            {
                ResultLabel.Text = "You entered: " + BarcodeEntry.Text;
                BarcodeEntry.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            BarcodeEntry.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

The Android renderer:

```
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyPCL.Views;
using MyPCL.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScanEntryControl), typeof(ScanEntryRenderer))]
namespace MyPCL.Droid
{
    public class ScanEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                ((ScanEntryControl)e.NewElement).PropertyChanging += OnPropertyChanging;
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                ((ScanEntryControl)e.OldElement).PropertyChanging -= OnPropertyChanging;
            }

            // Disable the Keyboard on Focus
            this.Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs propertyChangingEventArgs)
        {
            // Check if the view is about to get Focus
            if (propertyChangingEventArgs.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                // Dismiss the Keyboard 
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: @JoeLv, minSdkVersion = 15.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @JoeLv I appreciate your help, but my keyboard still flashes on the screen when using the renderer you provided. I edited my question to reflect the full code set. Ultimately I went with a completely different approach, which I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer does not solve the original issue directly, in the sense that it does not involve an Entry control. However, it was the only thing that worked for me, and ended up being a more elegant solution:

The Bluetooth scanner was in HID mode (Human Interface Device) by default, meaning the only way it could interact with the app was by imitating key presses, thereby necessitating an Entry (EditText) control, or similar. I switched the scanner to SPP mode (Serial Port Profile) and adapted the code from [this page](https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/connect-a-barcode-reader-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-via-bluetooth/) (see also the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestBth), and for more info on HID vs SPP see [this document](https://www.socketmobile.com/docs/default-source/white-papers/socketscan-10-sdk_white-paper.pdf?sfvrsn=2)).

The resulting code activates the scanner and then "listens" for input. When input is received, it is displayed in a Label rather than an Entry control.

There were other problems with the Entry control that I didn't mention prior: often it would add a repeat character to the front of the barcode and/or chop off one or more characters from the end. The SPP solution solved all that as well. If anyone wants the code I came up with, let me know. It will take some work to put together in a generic example, so not posting it at the moment.

Comment: this is just for Android, not for xamarin.Forms supporting all 3 platforms (or at least IOS and Android)?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to connect barcode scanner in SPP mode. but it is not working as expected, the code works for other Bluetooth scanned but not for Zebra and Honeywell readers. If you could post your code that would be really great..

Answer (score 2):

> I have been stumbling around writing custom controls and android renderers, and with setting up dependencies (preferred), both with partial success.

You can use `EditText.ShowSoftInputOnFocus` to achieve it in your `scanning page`, then the keyboard will not appear when your entry gets the focus:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Edi;
using Edi.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScanEntryControl), typeof(ScanEntryRenderer))]
namespace Edi.Droid
{
    public class ScanEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                ((ScanEntryControl)e.NewElement).PropertyChanging += OnPropertyChanging;
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                ((ScanEntryControl)e.OldElement).PropertyChanging -= OnPropertyChanging;
            }

            // Disable the Keyboard on Focus
            this.Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs propertyChangingEventArgs)
        {
            // Check if the view is about to get Focus
            if (propertyChangingEventArgs.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                // incase if the focus was moved from another Entry
                // Forcefully dismiss the Keyboard 
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In other pages you can still use `Entry`, so the keyboard will be appear.

### UPDATE:

`ScanEntryControl` class in PCL:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Edi
{
    public class ScanEntryControl : Entry
    {
    }
}
```

.xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Edi"
             x:Class="Edi.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:ScanEntryControl Text="ScanEntryControl"/>
            <Entry Text="Entry"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Joe Lv: I tried your solution but it does not work. Here's what I did: Added a custom entry control called ScanEntryControl. Added your example renderer as written, but swapping MyEntry for the name of my custom control. Added my custom control to the xaml layout. Perhaps I am missing something, but it never hits the renderer at all. I put this attribute before the namespace declaration on the renderer: [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScanEntryControl), typeof(ScanEntryRenderer))]

Comment: Could please show your code about the render? Or you can test it in firstly, because I have tested it already. I will post the complete code.

Comment: I have updated my answer and edited the `ScanEntryControl`, please try again.

Comment: Joe Lv: I fixed it so it does hit the renderer (there was a bug, my fault) but it still does not fix the original problem. With the renderer you provided, the keyboard "flashes" on the screen before disappearing. My goal is to make it so that the keyboard is never displayed, not even for a fraction of a second. In your solution, does the keyboard never show at all?

Comment: In my solution, the `ScanEntryControl` with render will never show when its page is current page, and I just show you the different between `ScanEntryControl` and `Entry` in my demo. By `the keyboard "flashes" on the screen before disappearing.`, I test my solution again, it never happen in my phone. Please try my solution again.

Comment: @Robbit Your solution absolutely does NOT work.  I have tried it multiple times and exactly as jshockwave explained, the keyboard shows, then gets hidden.  In fact, setting ShowSoftInputOnFocus  to false in onElementChanged seam to do nothing in Xamarin Forms although Android docs say it prevents keyboard from showing.  Your code therefore shows keyboard, then code inside OnPropertyChanging hides it resulting in keyboard flashing.  You took this code from this link https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/05/19/a-keyboard-disabled-entry-control-in-xamarin-forms/ which is nonesense ...

Comment: @Robbit ... you can even see that by looking at that link's author's gif.  It shows you regular entry as 1st field, which means keyboard shows, then switches to keyboardless entry below which hides keyboard.  If the reversed the order of the entries, you would clearly see keyboard flashing.  The author never bothered to even reply to any questions about this either.  So, if you say in your case it prevents keyboard from showing up, can you provide link to code to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        txtLotID.Focus();
    }

    private void OnLoad()
    {
        Init();

        swScanMode.IsToggled = Global.IsScannable;
        txtLotID.EnableKeyboard = !Global.IsScannable;
        txtLotID.OnEntryScanned += BtnSearch_Clicked;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            if (txtLotID.IsReadOnly)
            {
                txtLotID.Text = "";
                **txtLotID.IsReadOnly = false;**
                txtLotID.GetFocus();
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I had found one sample over in the Xamarin forums that IMHO contained the key solution:
You must override Focus() and must not call the base method. This gives you full control over the virtual keyboard. In all other solutions I have seen the virtual keyboard appears sometimes.

Of course your custom Entry needs methods to show/hide the keyboard. You would call them in your OnFocus() method. My sample control (see below) also has a bindable property that allows you to show the virtual keyboard automatically on Focus. So you may decide for every field if the keyboard should appear automatically or not.
In addition I have included another object that informs you if the virtual keyboard is currently visible and its size in case you need to size your layout accordingly.

Since this is quite a common question in several different forums I have decided to create a sample control and a small app to show the features. 
In addition I wrote a detailed Readme that explains all crucial points of the implementation.

You will find it here: https://github.com/UweReisewitz/XamarinAndroidEntry

Comment: This example is only for Xamarin.android?  Not for Xamarin.Forms and supporting of all 3 platforms?

Comment: This is for Xamarin Forms on Android. 
It contains a custom renderer that handles the specific problems one have on Android when trying to control the appearance and disappearance of the virtual keyboard.
We needed that on scanner devices, especially those that have a hardware keyboard. 
I'm thinking about adding iOS support but currently there are no plans for UWP since we do not support it in our app.